# How to retrieve worklog for a month from JIRA using JIRA REST API?

Tags: google-apps-script, jira, jira-rest-api

How to retrieve worklog for a particular month from JIRA using JIRA REST API? I am trying to fetch fields like issuekey, summary, comments, timeSpent and startdatetime. I tried to use GET /rest/api/3/worklog/updated with "since" in google app script. However "since" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't provide a sample of the request you sent to that endpoint, there is no way of knowing why the **since** parameter "is not working" for you.

Also, as per the [documentation for that endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-worklogs/#api-rest-api-3-worklog-updated-get) you are using, it only returns IDs of worklogs, therefore it cannot tell you anything about the value of fields like **issueKey**, **summary**, **comments** etc.